# Creating an autocorrelation matrix from start - R

Tags: r, lag, autocorrelation

I'm making a very dirty version of an autocorrelation function in R.

I have a loop that works up to a specified max lag and then returns all the correlations as a matrix, as the acf() function does.

The idea is to replicate the output of the acf() function as shown:

```
Autocorrelations of series ‘acfData’, by lag

     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8 
 1.000 -0.038  0.253  0.266  0.250  0.267 -0.182  0.281 -0.013 
     9     10     11     12     13 
-0.067 -0.122 -0.115 -0.023 -0.337
```

What I have so far is the input of data, the specified max lag and the code then works over the range by sliding the data frame back the needed amount and then performing the covariance and standard deviation calculations over the necessary range of data matrices. This is repeated over the range of lags and then appended to the matrices as shown, I also included the cor() function with the data frames created to test.

My problem is that the code returns the correct value for the first loop, or slide, and then returns slightly wrong values from then on.

```
myAcf <- function(dat, lg){

  dataF <- data.frame("data" = dat)
  names(dataF)[1] <- "acfData"
  lagMat <- c()
  testMat <- c()
  for(i in 0:lg){
    dataLag <- slide(dataF, "acfData", slideBy = -i)

    covacf <- cov(dataLag[(1+i):nrow(dataLag[1]), 1], dataLag[(1+i):nrow(dataLag[1]), 2])
    sd1 <- sd(dataLag[(1+i):nrow(dataLag[1]), 1])
    sd2 <- sd(dataLag[(1+i):nrow(dataLag[1]), 2])

    corrCalc <- covacf/(sd1 * sd2)
    lagMat <- c(lagMat, corrCalc)

    a <- cor(dataLag[(1+i):nrow(dataLag[1]), 1], dataLag[(1+i):nrow(dataLag[1]), 2])
    testMat <- c(testMat, a)
  }
  plot(lagMat)
  return(list(lagMat, testMat))
  }
```

My code then returns for the same data as the acf() function input:

```
[[1]]
 [1]  1.00000000 -0.03786539  0.27700596  0.30197418  0.31009956
 [6]  0.37123797 -0.19520518  0.44399863  0.05684766  0.02063488
[11] -0.03724332

[[2]]
 [1]  1.00000000 -0.03842146  0.27502462  0.29292583  0.35052131
 [6]  0.40931426 -0.23637159  0.52320559  0.07270497  0.02555461
[11] -0.04524035
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: There are many nuances to consider if you want exactly the same result: 1) `acf` has `demean = TRUE` which, I believe, means that for every lag you should use the same centering (sample mean), 2) since autocorrelation function assumes stationarity, I'd similarly expect the variance to be computed just once, from the whole sample, 3) there also isn't just one possible denominator; it may be T, T-h for lag h, etc. So, ultimately you really should take a look into the code of `acf`.